# How to add iPhone X simulator on Xcode8.3.3?

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I want to test my app on iPhone X. I don't want to run my current app on Xcode9 due to some designing issues. So Is there any way to test app on iPhone X simulator?. Please clarify me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible in xcode 8.x.x

Comment: The iPhone X supports iOS 11 as a minimum, therefore you need Xcode 9.

Comment: @Paulw11Yes, But if i run it on xcode9, But top view constraints are changing. So i want to test it on iPhone X simulator

Comment: @srinadh: You will have to live with that. And you need to test both with iOS 11 in general (which required me to make some changes), and very much with iPhone X.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, Xcode 9 is required to run your code on iPhone X Simulator. You can download [Xcode 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.0.1/Xcode_9.0.1.xip) or [Xcode 9.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.1/Xcode_9.1.xip) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest Xcode beta version, because beta versions are easily installed in parallel to your released Xcode version. Then run *a copy* of your project on the iPhone X simulator on Xcode 9 beta, and change the original to fix any problems that you find.

Comment: Why do you need Xcode beta? You can easily install Xcode 8 and the non-beta Xcode 9.1 in parallel. Besides that, building and running a copy of the project with Xcode 9 and an updated Base SDK of iOS 11.x is not at all a fair test to know if the same project built and released with Xcode 8 and a Base SDK of iOS 10.x will work the same or not on an iPhone X.